# AJAX getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm new to AJAX and have some problems understanding it.
I have this code:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        var titles = xmlhttp.responseText.getElementsByClassName('title');
        document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML=titles;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "index.html", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

This will produce the error: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".

I don't really understand why I can't get the classes, id's or anything from it.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`responseText` will be a string, not a DOM object.

Use [`responseXML`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-responsexml-attribute) instead.

Note that `getElementsByClassName` will return a NodeList, not a string of HTML, so you'll also need to process it before assigning it to `innerHTML`.